# Photoshop CC Extract Assets from layer, get individual assets, not entire layer as one single asset/png

Tags: adobe-photoshop

it used to be that I was able to extract all assets from a layer in a PSD, by right-clicking that layer in Photoshop and choosing "Extract Assets". This would bring up a view showing all the assets in that layer, and let me configure certain aspects of the process, such as what file type i would like the extracted assets to be, the asset resolutions, etc. I would then click extract, and get all the different assets from that layer in one nice folder, on my desktop.

Now, however, when I right-click a layer and click "extract assets", i get the same window, showing all the assets being extracted, but, and this is a big but, unfortunately only showing the ***entire layer*** as the only asset, in png format, or whatever i chose as the format for the assets.

How can i get back to extracting each individual asset within a layer, using the extract assets method?

Thanks!

c

Answer (score 1):

Aha, so, it seems, right-clicking the layer and selecting un-group layers fixed this. Not sure why it worked before for me though, maybe I had only been working with un-grouped layers.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really want to accept an answer that I have written myself, to a question I have also written myself as well. What I did did work for me though. If any mod thinks this should be marked as the right answer then, even though I answered the question myself, please let me know or mark it as the answer yourself.

Comment: If you select child layers in a layer group and right click on those layers you will be able to get uncomposed assets. Currently clicking on 'Extract Assets' in a layer group will create a single image asset.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstanding about layer and smart object layer...I guess your question is how to extract all the different elements of a smart object...

Here is how i do it...I make a group of all the elements in a button for example...Then if you want to extract the whole button then rename the group to btn.png and if you want its background separated then extend their name with .png

[image: how to extract assets from group and layers]

Answer (score 0):

If you add a file extention to the layers you want to extract, you get the separate layers when you use 'extract assets'.

Example:

[image]